# Pickaday add a day

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

I have two fields, arrival date and departure date. I have arrival set to show today. I'm trying to get the departure to show as tomorrow. I've tried a few things on StackOverflow to no avail and increased coffee usage.

Here is what I have. I'm happy to provide poor illustrations of an animal of your choice for any help, you have a lovely day!

```js
var pickerTheme = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('arrival-date2'),
  theme: 'dark-theme',
  bound: false,
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  minDate: moment().toDate(),
  onSelect: function() {
    //document.getElementById('arrival-date').value = "06/25/2021";
    const dateString = this.getMoment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    const parts = dateString.split('/');
    const month = parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1;
    const day = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    const year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

    document.getElementsByName('checkInDate')[0].value = day;
    document.getElementsByName('checkInMonthYear')[0].value = "" + month + year;
  }
});

var pickerTheme = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('departure-date2'),
  theme: 'dark-theme',
  bound: false,
  minDate: moment().toDate(),
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  onSelect: function() {
    //document.getElementById('arrival-date').value = "06/25/2021";
    const dateString = this.getMoment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    const parts = dateString.split('/');
    const month = parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1;
    const day = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    const year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

    document.getElementsByName('checkOutDate')[0].value = day;
    document.getElementsByName('checkOutMonthYear')[0].value = "" + month + year;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Pikaday with the moment.js library you can use moment's `add()` method to increment the day value:

```
const dateString = this.getMoment().add(1, 'd').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried adding that in to the second calendar..

Comment: but didnt seem to work - quick link here (click BOOK NOW in the middle of the big photos) https://www.barefootdev.co.uk/kimpton4/en/

Comment: Added here, maybe it shouldnt be in the onselect area: format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
     onSelect: function() {
      //document.getElementById('arrival-date').value = "06/25/2021";
                        const dateString = this.getMoment().add(1, 'd').format('MM/DD/YYYY');

      const parts = dateString.split('/');
      const month = parseInt(parts[0], 10) -1;